# Popup screen becomes full screen when application is full screen

Tags: fullscreen

I am using Eclipse. When I open popup window (e.g. "Open Resource") and the application is in fullscreen, the popup window also becomes fullscreen too. It is quite annoying. I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was using jdk8u152 which caused the issue. After I rollback to jdk8u151, the problem doesn't exist anymore.